# How to pass input values to Scheduled Jenkins pipeline job?

Tags: jenkins, input, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I have a Jenkins Pipeline which doesn't have any build parameter. But has `input` template inside. So, when a job is started using `Build now`, it gets triggered and waits for user input through `Input Requested` and the options are populated as choices.

This is working fine, when i run manually.
But, I want to enable default values for `input` choice variable, so that when a scheduled job starts, it will not wait for user input (through `Input Requested`) and continue to use default values.

My input template looks like this.

```
env.cluster_to_select = input(
                        id: 'cluster_to_select', message: 'Select a choice',
                        parameters: [
                                 choice(name: 'clusters',
                                       choices: env.list_files, //can take from populated string
                                       description: 'Based on cluster selection, nodes are shown'
                                        )
                        ]
                )
```

How to know if the job is triggered via scheduler and pass default values for input.

Answer (score 2):

You can wrap the `input` in a `timeout` block, which itself should be in a `try` block. Then catch the exception, check whether it timed out or was aborted by a user, and proceed accordingly with the default parameters or abort the build.

```
env.cluster_to_select = try {
                            timeout(time: 120, unit: 'SECONDS') {
                                input(
                                    id: 'cluster_to_select', message: 'Select a choice',
                                    parameters: [
                                        choice(name: 'clusters',
                                            choices: env.list_files, //can take from populated string
                                            description: 'Based on cluster selection, nodes are shown'
                                            )
                                        ]
                                    )
                                }
                            }   catch(err) { // timeout reached or input aborted by user
                                def user = err.getCauses()[0].getUser()
                                if (user.toString() == 'SYSTEM') { // SYSTEM is timeout
                                    echo('Using default parameters')
                                } else {
                                    currentBuild.result = 'ABORTED'
                                    error("Pipeline aborted by: [${user}]")
                                }
                            }
```

See [Pipeline: How to add an input step, with timeout, that continues if timeout is reached, using a default value](https://support.cloudbees.com/hc/en-us/articles/226554067-Pipeline-How-to-add-an-input-step-with-timeout-that-continues-if-timeout-is-reached-using-a-default-value).

Comment: is there any Jenkins groovy complete reference book? I tried many java codes , they do not work in Jenkins.

Comment: Though Groovy runs on JVM, it has many differences from Java. I haven’t come across any comprehensive reference material that specifically deals with Groovy for Jenkins. But you might go through these discrete references - 1. https://groovy-lang.org/documentation.html; 2. https://opensource.triology.de/jenkins/pipeline-syntax/globals; 3. https://javadoc.jenkins-ci.org/